# Meaning of "Real knicker-rotter"

Tags: phrases, idioms

I've just finished to read the book "Agatha Raisin and the Quiche of Death" and there is one sentence I don't really understand... What does "Real knicker-rotter" mean? Is there any word going instead of?
Sorry if my english is too bad, I'm not fluent, ahah.

['Here she comes!' screeched Roy, one of her assistants. 'Made some special champagne punch, Aggie. Real knicker-rotter.']

Comment: Did you copy correctly the expression? Please edit your question, not in a comment, and include the sentence with a link to the book if possible. Judging by the book's title, it looks like a parody of one of [Agatha Christie's](https://www.agathachristie.com/) detective stories.

Comment: Please provide additional context (for example, the entire sentence it appears in, possibly some sentences around it) - sometimes expressions are context-dependent.

Comment: _Realy_ is not an English word. As Mari-Lou said, more context is needed for the question to be complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a copy of the text online. I am reluctant to link to it for copyright reasons. The relevant text appears to be a line spoken by a character called Roy:

> Come on. Let’s go into the kitchen. I’ve made a spe­cial champagne punch, Aggie. It’s a real knicker rotter.

This is a scene set at a party. I am not aware that "knicker rotter" is standard slang. (An online search seems to produce only references to the novel or people asking about it.)

The implication is that the punch is very strong. I can think of several reasons why the phrase might be used to mean that, with various degrees of vulgarity. Perhaps the least vulgar would be that it might cause the drinker to become so inebriated that they wet their underpants (knickers). There could be sexual innuendoes as well.

Comment: Oh. I made a mistake when I wrote the sentence, sorry! Thank you for your answer, James Random!

Comment: @Yukichi 'Knicker rotter' sounds really weird to me (just the mouth feel) but if you rewrite it it kind of makes sense: a rotter of knickers, something that will make you knickers rot, something that will make you ruin you knickers. 'rot' sounds weird to me here, but maybe, as an American, it's British slang I'm not used to.

Comment: I'll consider the sentence that way then (that sth will make somebody ruin his knickers). You both are surely right! Thank you for your help :).